# Swimming to a Boat

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, kinematics

A boat is travelling on a bearing of $α=60^\circ$
 at a constant speed $u=3.0$  $m/s$.
 A man is swimming at a constant speed $v$
in order to reach the boat from a point a distance $l=100\ m$
due east of the boat.

Find, as a bearing, the direction in which the swimmer should head in order to reach the boat with the minimum speed.

What then is the minimum value of $v$
 which will enable the swimmer to reach the boat.

What is the time taken for the swimmer to reach the boat with this speed?

Comment: Draw a picture, post it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the picture looks like this.  Let $t$ be the time the man reaches the boat.  So, from the figure, $$tu\sin\theta=tv\sin\varphi$$
and $$tu\cos\theta-tv\cos\varphi=l.$$
That is,
$$v=\sqrt{v^2\sin^2\varphi+v^2\cos^2\varphi}=\sqrt{u^2\sin^2\theta+\left(u\cos\theta-\frac{l}{t}\right)^2}\geq u\sin\theta.$$
The minimum value $v_\min=u\sin\theta$ is achievable by swimming northward (i.e., with $\varphi=90^\circ$).  The time $t^*$ it takes will be $\frac{l}{u\cos\theta}$.

With $\theta=60^\circ$, $u=3.0\ \text{m}/\text{s}$, and $l=100\ \text{m}$, we have $v_\min=u\sin\theta=2.6\ \text{m}/\text{s}$.  The time it takes is $t^*=\frac{l}{u\cos\theta}=67\ \text{s}$.

[image]